# not all POST data are received/handled by Cake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a `PresentationsController` which handles some POST action form. In this form I have data related to Presentation such as:

```
<input name="data[Presentation][title]" class="init-focus span4" type="text" id="PresentationTitle" required="required">
```

and those fields are handled correctly by controller. But `PresentationModel` hasMany `Subject`. So I want to include some presentation subjects in form. I did it like this:

```
<input name="data[Subject][0][subject]" disabled="disabled" class="subject" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Subject0Subject" required="required">
<input name="data[Subject][1][subject]" disabled="disabled" class="subject" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Subject0Subject" required="required">
```

But those data are not handled by Cake - I tried `var_dump($this->request->data)` in Controller but they are missing... for some reason Cake just ignores those data...

---

I am generating inputs dynamicalyy with jquery but it inputs are added correctly to form - I can see them in my browser html elements viewer:

```
<input name="data[Subject][0][subject]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Subject0Subject" required="required">
<input name="data[Subject][1][subject]" disabled="disabled" class="subject" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Subject0Subject" required="required">
```

The above is what I view in html elements viewer - the first input is added "inline" from php and second is added dynamically with jquery. And only the first one is visible after POST.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using the FormHelper?

Comment: Well I am using form helper. But for a "template" - I copy it with jquery to add many inputs dynamicaly in my form - I just change the [n] index in inputs name. The inputs are added to the form correctly as I can see them in my browser (Chrome) html elements tree. But those added dynamicaly are not sent...

Comment: Assuming your using some sort of for loop to set these up you can still use the form helpers.  Set them to name them as 'Subject.'.$i.'.subject'  Essentially this will return arrays of [Subject][$i][subject] that can be automatically saved.

Comment: Please also note that you have a duplicate id `id="Subject0Subject"` used on both inputs (0 and 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set an input to `disabled="disabled"` it is NOT submitted.  That goes for normal HTML and is not something CakePHP specific.

According to W3Schools.com:

> Disabled  elements in a form will not be submitted.

Comment: Yeass, thats it thanks - is there any other option to show input that is uneditable to user but posted in form?